# I keep getting this Debug Assertion Failed? Expression: list iterator not dereferenceable

Tags: c++

I'm getting an assertion failure "list iterator not dereferencable" from the following code:

It says that it is from the last line.

```
void cpuschedule::Sjf()
{
    int CT = 0;
    bool IO = false;
    Data temp;

    for(it = lPro.begin(); it != lPro.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->RQ)
        {
            temp.AT = it->AT;
            temp.BUT = it->BUT;
            temp.BUP = it->BUP;
            temp.IOP = it->IOP;
            temp.IOT = it->IOT;
            temp.ProNum = it->ProNum;
            temp.RQ = it->RQ;
            temp.vData = it->vData;
            Ready.push_back(temp);
        }
    }    

    it2 = Ready.begin();

    while(!(Ready.empty()))
    {

        if(IO)
        {
            for(iR = Ready.begin(); iR != Ready.end(); ++iR)
            {
                if(!(iR->RQ))
                {
                    (iR->IOT)--;
                    if(iR->IOT == 0)
                    {
                        iR->BUP += 2;
                        iR->IOP += 2;
                        iR->BUT = iR->vData[(iR->BUP)];
                        iR->IOT = iR->vData[(iR->IOP)];

                        iR->RQ = true;
                        iR->AT = CT;
                    }

                    if(iR->IOT == -121)//Check for the end of the Vector
                    {
                        temp.AT = iR->AT;
                        temp.BUT = iR->BUT;
                        temp.BUP = iR->BUP;
                        temp.IOP = iR->IOP;
                        temp.IOT = iR->IOT;
                        temp.ProNum = iR->ProNum;
                        temp.RQ = iR->RQ;
                        temp.vData = iR->vData;
                        Out.push_back(temp);//Instert to the List of Done

                        iR = Ready.erase(iR);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Ready.sort(comp);

        if((it2->BUT != 0) && (it2->RQ))
        {
            it2->BUT--;

            if(it2->BUT == 0)
            {

                printState(CT);

                it2->RQ = false;
                IO = true;

                if(next(it2) == Ready.end())
                {

                    it2 = Ready.begin();

                }
                else
                    ++it2;
            }
        }

    CT++;
    }

}
```

This is a while loop for a CPU Scheduling SJF.
It goes up to 691 and it should do 901 loops

Comment: That's a big slice of code and I can't see that you've indicated which line the crash is on, but - you should maybe check that iterator `it2` for the container you're using remains valid after the `erase()` and `sort()` operations.  Move the declaration of `it2` down to just before it's used, which is probably better style regardless.

Comment: How does your `it` and `lPro` look like? Can you show us where did you declare them?

Comment: I'm sure most of this code isn't needed to reproduce the problem. Post a smaller version that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop performs `iR = Ready.erase(iR);` and then does `iR++` anyway. This is wrong, if the element erased was the last one; you go one-over-the-end.

The common idiom is:

```
for ( ; iR != end; ) { // <-- NO iR++
   if (condition_to_erase)
      iR = Ready.erase(iR);
   else
      iR++;
}
```